# How can I get all of the types defined in a package in Go that implement an interface?

Tags: reflection, go

If I have the structure:

```
api > v1 > *.go
```

I would like to be able to `import api.v1` and from that, reflect out any of the types defined therein that satisfy, say, `http.Handler`.

I have reflect of types and methods down, but I can't seem to figure out how to just inspect anything that has a `package v1` declaration and extract all types defined in there. Is this impossible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the strong feeling that you approach whatever problem you have from the wrong side. Consider taking the approach the package image takes and let each implementation register itself during its initialization.

Comment: @FUZxxl I finally got there. When I did, it felt _much_ cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the imported code the compiler will not include it, so I think it's impossible.

If you are running the code somehow anyway (so it is included) you might as well just have it call a register function to register itself.

Programming in Go usually doesn't include the sort of "magic" you are asking for. At first it felt limiting to me, but I got used to it after a while and now I appreciate that things are what they look like, if that makes sense.

Comment: I discovered init() and _ imports, which seems to have let me rethink the problem in a much better (or, "Go-ish") fashion. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Have fun, I know I do when I play with Go. :-)